# How to remove default divs on views result?

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to add use bootstrap modal and bootstrap slideshow to show a view but the slideshow doesn't work the way I want it because of the default generated divs by Views module. Here is the code:

```
    <div id="block-views-custom-package-form-venue-option" class="block block-views">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>heading 1</h4>
                    <p>This is the description.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>heading 2</h4>
                    <p>This is the description.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the result of the view supposedly like this:

```
<div class="item active">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>heading 1</h4>
        <p>This is the description.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>heading 2</h4>
        <p>This is the description.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only the output of the view with no views default generated divs.

Comment: finally do you solve your problem? If one of the answer help you, you can check it as accepted ;-) –

Answer (score 2):

Go to the **Settings** of your **Fields** and uncheck the Option: **Provide default field wrapper elements**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [semantic views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews) module to strip tags

> This Views plugin makes unformatted styles, field row styles and other
>   output more readily configurable without needing to override template
>   files. Instead of overriding row style templates for views where you
>   want to specify different HTML elements (tags) and class attributes,
>   you can specify these inside the Views UI and avoid overriding
>   templates for each view.

Answer (score 1):

You can markup anything you'd like in views theming information. See the attached picture below.

Create a .tpl file using the "Display output". The highlighted ones are being used or the default ones. See below on how to do it:-

- Create a .tpl file using the theme suggestions in the display output eg. "views-view--machinename--page.tpl.php".
- Click the "Rescan template files". (The views-view--machinename--page.tpl.php will be highlighted when you've created it properly).
- Click the "Display output" link.
- Copy the opening php tags until at the end of its php tags, then paste that in "views-view--machinename--page.tpl.php".
- Click the OK button, then Flush all caches.

[image]